# WL.Device.startAcquisition - both success and failure callbacks are called?

Tags: android, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

I downloaded IBM MobileFirst project from https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-topics/location-services-hybrid-applications/.

I've ran it in the Android Emulator.

I've noticed that the method `WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition`, works as expected.
But with `WL.Device.startAcquisition`, after the `success` callback has been invoked, the `failure` callback invoked as well.

Why is the failure callback being triggered?

Comment: Can you provide the LogCat log from the time of the error?

Comment: Additionally, could you provide:

Answer (score 0):

Please see my above requests in the comment for additional information (as well as Idan's request).

Without that, though, my guess is that you're passing in a timeout on the Geo policy. When you're running in the emulator it's quite likely that you wind up not setting a value quickly enough (after the initial one you set), and thus soon after you're getting a timeout failure.

As well, please note that the Android emulator has a known bug that Geo positions are set starting from midnight on the current date.